# Stored procedure with mulitple queries in ORACLE

Tags: oracle11g

I have a stored procedure named `edit_emp` inside this stored procedure I have some 10 update queries.

Now I get an error in the 5th update statement - what will happen to the rest of the update query? Will it terminate in the 5th update line or will it execute the rest of the update queries?

Comment: What would you like to do when an error occur at any of your update statements?

Comment: Right now I don have any Error handler. I just want to know will my procedure run fully or will terminate when it gets error in the query

Comment: @LogeshwaranVeluchamy Well if you do not have any error handling block, then procedure will terminate when error occurs.

Comment: @LogeshwaranVeluchamy See the following, it might be helpful [this](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e25519/errors.htm#LNPLS851),[this](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e25519/errors.htm#LNPLS8530) and [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11966020/begin-end-block-atomic-transactions-in-pl-sql)

Answer (score 0):

`EXCEPTION WHEN OTHERS THEN`

// DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE ('Error');

`CONTINUE`;

Just add Exception Handler in ur procedure