# Rollback and drop table while exception handling in pl sql

Tags: oracle, plsql

Here is the scenario, I am writing a procedure which performs DML(insert) operations on multiple tables. In case of exception I need to rollback data from most of two table and drop a newly created table.

Example:

Procedure{

```
  1 create  table1

  2 insert into table2

  3 insert into table3


  Exception 
   WHEN OTHERS THEN
        IF DBMS_SQL.IS_OPEN(cur) THEN
    DBMS_SQL.CLOSE_CURSOR(cur);
  END IF;
  RAISE;
```

}

Now the question is that if insert fails on table2 then I need to drop table1 as well and if insert fails on  table3 then I need to rollback the insert that has already happened on table2 and also drop table1.

I'm  not sure how to do that in the "Exception" part of pl-sql procedure. Any help would be highly appreciated. Though I looked at this [Create oracle table with auto commit on](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24419183/create-oracle-table-with-auto-commit-on) but this scenario doesn't match mine 100% (somewhat though). All suggestion will be highly apprecaited.

Comment: if insertion failed in table2 do you want to continue with inserting into table3?

Comment: The thing is if the insertion fails on table2 program flow would go to exception (and the entire execution would stop) so no question of inserting data in to table3 arises, right?

Comment: Why you need to create a table as part of the procedure ?

Comment: Actually someone else did that and left so I have been asked not to make any changes in the already existing plsql code but also make sure if inserts fail then either drop table1 or drop table1 and clean table2.

Answer (score 0):

according to the question and comments, using `SAVEPOINT` is a good idea for this scenario:

```
  1 create  table1;

  SAVEPOINT SPT;

  2 insert into table2;

  3 insert into table3;

  Exception 
   WHEN OTHERS THEN
   --your code;
  ROLLBACK TO SPT; 
  DROP TABLE table1;
```

Comment: That looks fine, but don't you think that  create table being a DDL statement does an auto-commit so even if I Rollback up to the savepoint, still table1 will exist in the database. Since we can't rollback something that we have already committed.

Comment: @user2913184, correct, sorry for not paying more attention on detail just let me to edit the question

Comment: so think on using `GOTO lable` with `nested` exception blocks

Comment: Again I will run into a problem if I do Drop table table1 Rollback to spt, since drop is again a ddl statement so it will autocommit whatever has been inserted in table2 and table3.

Comment: No, not on exactly like this one, I just want to give some possible hints

Comment: I'm  not sure whether I can take this hint drop a table and then do a rollback.

Comment: Test it, I have not any Oracle DB on this computer which I'm posting with otherwise surly I'd gave a good solution, anyway I hope you'll get a good solution

Comment: I guess question of testing doesn't arise as of now since Drop table table1 Rollback to spt will surely do an autocommit on drop statement execution and after that Rollback to spt won't do what it is supposed to do.

Comment: Just perform the rollback *then* drop the table.

Comment: Ok, I will follow your code Farhang according to Tommcatt's suggestion and then will test it and will let you all know the results.

Comment: Just  a silly question Farhang that rollback and drop statements should come just before Raise keyword in my exception handling code ? Bear with me since im pretty new to plsql.

Comment: @user2913184 you are very welcome, don't say that plz, we all are here to improve our knowledge and experience, even for very experienced people there is something that they never experienced, I told you I never experienced exactly a scenario like this and you have to try and test, and yes I think it should be before `raise` statement. also as I mentioned before you can think on `nested blocks and exception` and you may use `GOTO` inside it.