# Why is this sql query giving syntax error?

Tags: sql, oracle

```
begin transaction;
update employee set id = id/10;
update sales set employee_id = employee_id/10;
commit;
```

The error message:

```
Error starting at line 1 in command:
begin transaction;
update employee set id = id/10;
update sales set employee_id = employee_id/10;
commit; 
Error report:
ORA-06550: line 4, column 8:
PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "end-of-file" when expecting one of the following:

   ( begin case declare end exception exit for goto if loop mod
   null pragma raise return select update while with
   <an identifier> <a double-quoted delimited-identifier>
   <a bind variable> << continue close current delete fetch lock
   insert open rollback savepoint set sql execute commit forall
   merge pipe purge
06550. 00000 -  "line %s, column %s:\n%s"
*Cause:    Usually a PL/SQL compilation error.
*Action:
```

Comment: Try removing the semicolons

Comment: I think you are missing an `end;` statement after the `commit;` all begin should end with an end. Try it, if it works, I will add as an answer

Comment: i´ve never heard of `begin transaction` in combination with an `oracle` database. I´d say that it interprets it as `begin...end` and is looking for the `end` statement.

Comment: I think there already an answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/11979726/460557

Comment: There is no "begin transaction" command in Oracle.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [BEGIN - END block atomic transactions in PL/SQL](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11966020/begin-end-block-atomic-transactions-in-pl-sql)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```
begin 
update employee set id = id/10;
update sales set employee_id = employee_id/10;
commit;
end;
```

Comment: Error starting at line 1 in command:
begin 
update employee set id = id/10;
update sales set employee_id = employee_id/10;
commit;
end;
Error report:
ORA-02290: check constraint (MSAQIB.EMPLOYEE_CHK1) violated
ORA-06512: at line 2
02290. 00000 -  "check constraint (%s.%s) violated"
*Cause:    The values being inserted do not satisfy the named check
           
*Action:   do not insert values that violate the constraint.

Comment: @anonymous:- Those errors clearly state that you are updating the values which are violating the constraints of your table columns. Please check the constraints and then make the query accordingly

Comment: Mybe you shoukld drop the offending constraint, make your uopdates and then recreate the contstraint.

Comment: @anonymous in order to do what you want you will have to disable all constraints of employee table to another tables then you run this block.