# What is the common roll back logic in Oracle PL/SQL

Tags: oracle, plsql

I am newbie in Oracle PL/SQL programming but trying to learn how to make all queries in a PL/SQL within one transaction and properly rollback if anything goes wrong among those queries, following is the pattern I made to serve the purpose:

```
create or replace procedure transaction_safe(var in varchar2)
is 
begin
    SAVEPOINT start_point;
    /* a lot of DML queries here....*/
    EXCEPTION
        WHEN OTHERS THEN
            ROLLBACK TO start_point;
end;
```

Does it make sense to have above `SAVEPOINT` / `EXCEPTION` / `ROLLBACK` block in PL/SQL or not necessary at all?

Comment: It looks duplicated as https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11966020/begin-end-block-atomic-transactions-in-pl-sql?rq=1

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## What is SAVEPOINT for?

The Oracle 10.2 docs have a [good summary of the purpose of SAVEPOINT](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/appdev.102/b14261/savepoint_statement.htm)

> With the `ROLLBACK TO` statement, savepoints undo parts of a transaction instead of the whole transaction.

and

> An implicit savepoint is marked before executing an `INSERT`, `UPDATE`, or `DELETE` statement. If the statement fails, a rollback to the implicit savepoint is done. Normally, just the failed SQL statement is rolled back, not the whole transaction; if the statement raises an unhandled exception, the host environment (such as SQL*Plus) determines what is rolled back.

You've written

> make all queries in a PL/SQL within one transaction

`SAVEPOINT` is useless in this situation - as is stated it's used for undong part of a transaction. If every query is in one transaction with a savepoint forced at the beginning then it can't help us at all.

## The procedure

I think there's a few things you're missing:

- You can't guarantee that all queries sit within that initial transaction.

  Take a batch job with two steps each step using up significant amount of temp space. If you run both steps without committing between them then you might run out of temp space causing issues for your and other processes running.

  I think we have to assume that you might have a multi-stage and therefore multi-procedure process
- You're not raising exceptions. This means if you've got a data error you're never going to know about it. You must raise this exception to the calling code to decide how to handle it. If every layer of Oracle code raises an exception, i.e. the issue is exceptional, then the statements will rollback automatically.

As a minimum your procedure must be:

```
create or replace procedure transaction_safe(var in varchar2) is 
begin
  savepoint start_point;

exception when others then
   rollback to start_point;
   raise; -- the important part
end;
```

We're probably going to end up with a calling construct that very broadly looks like:

```
procedure run_process is
begin
   transaction1;
   commit;
   transaction2;
   commit;
exception when ...
   ...
end;
```

That procedure should really be a scheduler chain but putting it like this serves the purpose of making it easy to see.

## How might this be used?

I can think of three possibilities

### 1. On it's own

```
begin
   transaction1();
   commit;
end;
```

There are no immediate issues, the calling code is doing the commit logic, we've added an exception to your procedure so we get informed of errors. If we read [the documentation for `ROLLBACK`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/12.2/sqlrf/ROLLBACK.html#GUID-94551F0C-A47F-43DE-BC68-9B1C1ED38C93), it says:

> Oracle recommends that you explicitly end transactions in application programs using either a COMMIT or ROLLBACK statement. If you do not explicitly commit the transaction and the program terminates abnormally, then Oracle Database rolls back the last uncommitted transaction.

You've got `COMMIT` and `ROLLBACK` stated but it's not very explicit because your transaction control is in multiple places. Were we to put it in the same place it should be in the calling code rather than your procedure, though doing so makes the two functionally pretty similar

```
procedure run_process is
begin
   transaction1();
   commit;
exception when others then
   rollback;
   raise;
end;
```

This also makes code more reusable. `transaction1()` stripped of transaction logic can be called from multiple places as much as is required. Because if everything blows up then everything is rolled back we're not concerned about other procedures having poor transaction control logic as they only commit in calling code.

### 2. Executing multiple "transactions"

Let's assume that you now raise exceptions in your procedure and we're not committing between "transactions"

```
procedure run_process is
begin
   transaction1();
   transaction2();
   commit;
exception when others then
   rollback;
   raise;
end;
```

Let's assume that `transaction1()` failed and rolled back. An exception is raised hitting our outer exception handler. The rollback logic within the procedure is not required.

Just in case, if you don't raise an exception in `transaction1()` then your data might be left in an inconsistent because `transaction2()` will start running.

If you're running `transaction1()` and `transaction2()` on the scheduler then they are just two discrete examples of (1).

### 3. Executing multiple transactions in a loop

In other words, your calling code looks like the following:

```
procedure run_process() is
begin
   for i in (...) loop
      begin
         transaction1();
      exception when others then
         log();
      end;
   end loop;
end;
```

In this situation you might not want a single failure to prevent processing of your batch (if you do this is an example of (1)). This is where you're undoing parts of a transaction rather than the whole transaction and therefore using savepoints make sense. I'd still put them in the calling code though:

```
procedure run_process() is
begin
   for i in (...) loop
      begin
         savepoint blah;
         transaction1();
      exception when others then
         log();
         rollback to blah;
      end;
   end loop;
end;
```

---

**tl;dr**

You shouldn't *always* use savepoints so they should go in the calling code to ensure code reusability.

Comment: WoW, perfect answer. Unfortunately I can only mark it as answer one time.. :) Thank you !